# Swift - How is Instagram doing this?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I'm trying to achieve something similar to what Instagram does when you click on 3 dots on the right of the screen under the picture. Here's what it looks like before you click the dots:

[image]

And here's what it looks like after:

[image]

Obviously my scrolling feed of pictures is a UITableView, but my question is, when I click the 3 dots and it brings up this second view with a list of options, is this another UITableView, or do you think they're just bringing up a UIView?

What is the best option to use in a scenario like this?

Comment: Have you looked at `UIActionSheet`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They show a customise action sheet

Here are some of the example you can see below links can help you :)
This Solution are in Objective C you can use them using bridging header if i find a solution in swift i ill update the post :

[How to customize UIActionSheet? iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946358/how-to-customize-uiactionsheet-ios)

https://github.com/ianb821/IBActionSheet

> Here is the swift example

https://github.com/KyoheiG3/SimpleAlert

Answer (score 6):

In addition to O-mkar's answer, here is an open source Swift library for a UIActionController that is pretty customizable and up-to-date:

https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController

This is how your custom action sheet would look like, actually are  examples contained in the github repository project.

  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]