# Customised UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

How can I customise `UIActionSheet` to look like this :

[image]

Also, if I customise `UIActionSheet`, will there be a chance of app getting rejected ?

Comment: As long as you are using public apis from Apple, they won't reject your application, but it depends how much this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946358/how-to-customize-uiactionsheet-ios) will help you.

Comment: apple wont reject your app,

Comment: @gotnull : Well, I was not satisfied with the answer mentioned in above link :)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik You cannot guarantee that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really want to do something like that you could give this a go. I can't guarantee it'll be approved by Apple and honestly, it's just not recommended from a UI and Apple HIG perspective.

Keep in mind `UIActionSheet` has been deprecated and it's recommended to use `UIAlertController` with a `preferredStyle` of `.ActionSheet` so that's what this example is going to use.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let controller = SwiftDemoAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset to default", style: .Destructive, handler: nil))
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

class SwiftDemoAlertController: UIAlertController, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var controller : UITableViewController

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        controller = UITableViewController(style: .Plain)
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        controller.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        controller.tableView.dataSource = self
        controller.tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: [.Initial, .New], context: nil)
        self.setValue(controller, forKey: "contentViewController")
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        guard keyPath == "contentSize" else {
            return
        }

        controller.preferredContentSize = controller.tableView.contentSize
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {
        controller.tableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!

        switch(indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Upcoming activities"
            let switchView = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero)
            cell.accessoryView = switchView
            switchView.setOn(true, animated: false)
            break
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Past activities"
            let switchView = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero)
            cell.accessoryView = switchView
            switchView.setOn(false, animated: false)
            break
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Activities where I am admin"
            let switchView = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero)
            cell.accessoryView = switchView
            switchView.setOn(true, animated: false)
            break
        case 3:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Attending"
            let switchView = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero)
            cell.accessoryView = switchView
            switchView.setOn(true, animated: false)
            break
        case 4:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Declined"
            let switchView = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero)
            cell.accessoryView = switchView
            switchView.setOn(true, animated: false)
            break
        case 5:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Not responded"
            let switchView = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero)
            cell.accessoryView = switchView
            switchView.setOn(true, animated: false)
            break
        default:
            fatalError()
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

[image: Demo App]

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I can't go for it as it might get rejected. I might go for a UITableView though.

Comment: Can I have this in objective c ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you can create your own custom control by subclassing a `UIView` and then add a `UITableView` into that `View`. Then you can create rows with custom cell having a label and `UISwitch`, and having a footer view to create reset and save in the footer of the `UITableview`. After that make that custom view transparent background. then pass an array of options to that view to create rows in the that custom control.