# UIAlertController SheetView with custom images like WhatsApp IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have been struggling to find a solution for a UIAlertController Sheet View with images. My goal is to add a UIAlertController SheetView with left aligned labels and custom images on the right, like you can see in this screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq0qO.jpg).

I already tried other solutions but none of them were useful/ answered.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't comment. Can you provide the solutions and/or frameworks you've tried?

The thread here seems quite in-depth: [How to customize UIActionSheet? iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946358/how-to-customize-uiactionsheet-ios)

It references several libraries like https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController

`UIAlertController` is not very configurable. You'll need a library or create your own custom one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´ve already tried to make my own sheetView from scratch, but I've kinda failed at that. I think the best solution for me now is to try to make my own sheet view, but I´ll look into the frameworks you´ve provided.